# Mysql stored procedure array parameter from java

Tags: java, mysql

I need to create mysql stored procedure which makes more than one insert at a time. To prevent many calls to database I need to use stored procedure. I have `java.util.List<MyEntity>` object of my data. `MyEntity` is an object which holds data which has to be inserted into table.

My question is how should I pass List object as mysql procedure parameter?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's another way: batch the calls to the database.  You don't need a stored procedure for this.  Look at [java.sql.PreparedStatement.addBatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/).